# open hive exception error in drawer test , flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:talawa/constants/custom_theme.dart';
import 'package:talawa/models/mainscreen_navigation_args.dart';
import 'package:talawa/services/graphql_config.dart';
import 'package:talawa/services/navigation_service.dart';
import 'package:talawa/services/size_config.dart';
import 'package:talawa/utils/app_localization.dart';
import 'package:talawa/view_model/main_screen_view_model.dart';
import 'package:talawa/views/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:talawa/widgets/custom_alert_dialog.dart';
import '../../helpers/test_helpers.dart';
import '../../helpers/test_helpers.mocks.dart';
import '../../helpers/test_locator.dart';

class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}

Widget createHomePageScreen() {
  return MaterialApp(
    locale: const Locale('en'),
    localizationsDelegates: [
      const AppLocalizationsDelegate(isTest: true),
      GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
      GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
    ],
    themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
    theme: TalawaTheme.lightTheme,
    home: MainScreen(
      key: const Key('MainScreen'),
      mainScreenArgs: MainScreenArgs(mainScreenIndex: 0),
    ),
  );
}

void main() {
  testSetupLocator();

  setUp(() {
    registerServices();
    locator<SizeConfig>().test();
    locator<GraphqlConfig>().test();
  });

  group('Exit Button', () {
     testWidgets("Tapping Tests for Exit", (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createHomePageScreen());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = const Size(4000, 4000);
      MainScreenViewModel.scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      final leaveOrg = find.byKey(MainScreenViewModel.keyDrawerLeaveCurrentOrg);
      await tester.tap(leaveOrg);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      final dialogPopUP = verify(
              (locator<NavigationService>() as MockNavigationService)
                  .pushDialog(captureAny),)
          .captured;
      expect(dialogPopUP[0], isA<CustomAlertDialog>());
      // calling success() to have complete code coverage.
      dialogPopUP[0].success();
    });
  });
  group('Custom Drawer Test', () {
    testWidgets("Widget Testing", (tester) async {
      // pumping the Widget
      await tester.pumpWidget(createHomePageScreen());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // Opening the Drawer so that it can be loaded in the widget tree and built() is called
      await tester.dragFrom(
          tester.getTopLeft(find.byType(MaterialApp)), const Offset(300, 0));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // getting the Finders for Code Coverage
      expect(find.byKey(const ValueKey("Drawer")), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byKey(const ValueKey("Custom Drawer")), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text("Selected Organization"), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text("Switch Organization"), findsOneWidget);
      final listOfOrgs = find.byKey(const ValueKey("Switching Org"));
      expect(listOfOrgs, findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byKey(MainScreenViewModel.keyDrawerCurOrg), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byKey(MainScreenViewModel.keyDrawerSwitchableOrg),
          findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byType(UserAccountsDrawerHeader), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text("Join new Organization"), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text("Leave Current Organization"), findsOneWidget);
      final fromPalisadoes = find.byKey(const ValueKey("From Palisadoes"));
      expect(fromPalisadoes, findsOneWidget);
    });
    testWidgets("Tapping Tests for Org", (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createHomePageScreen());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // Opening the Drawer so that it can be loaded in the widget tree and built() is called
      await tester.dragFrom(
          tester.getTopLeft(find.byType(MaterialApp)), const Offset(300, 0));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      final orgs = find.byKey(const ValueKey("Org"));
      // Atleast One Org should be there
      // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
      expect(orgs.allCandidates.isEmpty, false);
      await tester.tap(orgs.first);
      // Was not required but done for code Coverage
      // Sized
      final sizedbox = find.byKey(const ValueKey("Sized Box Drawer"));
      // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
      expect(sizedbox.allCandidates.isEmpty, false);
    });
    testWidgets("Tapping Tests for Join", (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(createHomePageScreen());
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      tester.binding.window.physicalSizeTestValue = const Size(800, 4000);
      MainScreenViewModel.scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      final joinOrg = find.byKey(MainScreenViewModel.keyDrawerJoinOrg);
      await tester.tap(joinOrg);
      // await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    });
  });

  tearDown(() {
    unregisterServices();
  });
}
```

I am trying to write test for custom drawer and exit button but facing issues
it is giving exceptions

it is giving many exceptions like open hive Box exception can anyone please tell me what's wrong I am not using hive in this .

jhbdhilshblhsdbchlsbdchulsb hdsbcildhs vlhusdbcshd hsbdcushbc iusjb  ishb dsjbchjsbhjschjsdb chsdbcsh c sbchjdnbh c

Comment: it'd be useful if you add some more context and some detailed information of where the test fails and what exception is thrown exactly.

Comment: It is giving open Hive box exception